# Is it possible to pass multiple functions to navigation items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logout

I'm quite new to React.js and I need to add a logout link to a hamburger menu. In the parent component there is already defined an onClick -function for all the NavLinks, but I have the new logout button there which needs to be passed the logout-function instead. I'm not quite sure how to achieve that. I've tried several approaches that came to my mind, but they either were fired immediately when the nav was loaded or crashed the component.

The Nav is a an array of objects. A couple of NavLink items are visible only on mobile sizes and that part I got working already, but how to make the log out link work only when clicking that specific item?

Any help is appreciated.

```
   return (
  <li className={liClassnames}>
    <OTNavLink
      activeClassName="is-active"
      disabled={disabled}
      link={link}
      isExternal={isExternal}
      to={link}
      className={linkClassNames}
      /*onClick={(e) => {         // This code was here originally
        toggleNavigation(e);
      }}*/
        onClick={(e) => {          // And this is how I last tested whether altering this 
          SessionUtils.logout(e);  // changes the links behaviour
        }}                         // it naturally did for all the links
      {...linkAttributes}
    >
```

Here is the OTNavLink -components code you asked :)

```
const OTNavLink = (props) => {


let {link, isExternal = false, disabled, children,  ...rest} = props;

  let restForAnchor = omit(rest,["activeClassName", "disabled", "to"]);
  if (disabled) {
    return (
      <a {...restForAnchor}>
        {children}
      </a>
    )
  }

  // unwrap link (this should be unnecessary but applies to some cases)
  let _link = isEmpty(link) ? "javascript:void();" : isFunction(link) ? link() : link;

  if (isExternal) {
    return (
      <a
        href={_link}
        {...restForAnchor}
      >
        {children}
      </a>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <NavLink
        to={_link}
        {...rest}
      >
        {children}
      </NavLink>
    )
  }
};
```

And here's an example of the NavigationItems array:
It consists of multiple similar objects. some are rendered on mobile and hidden in desktop.

```
  let navigationItems = [
    {
      message: "navigation.timeline",
      disabled: false,
      icon: {
        type:"custom",
        name:"my-name"
      },
      link: "/timeline",
      key: "timeline"
    },
```

How can I pass a different function call to that one last logout link?

If you need any more details let me know :)

Comment: Welcome to SO @JTL, can you also share OTNavLink code?

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed a solution myself in the end. It was so simple all along. Although someone can tell me if there is a better way. :)

I just made a ternary check in the custom component, so it will apply to only the links that have that message property.

```
onClick={this.props.message === 'logout' ? (e) => SessionUtils.logout(e) : (e) => {
            toggleNavigation(e);
          }}
```